# Defining projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I'm still studying basic Algebraic Geometry by myself and I got to the point of moving to the projective space. It's clear that there is a need of using homogeneous polynomials to keep the notion of belonging to a projective variety.

The thing that stumps me is defining the algebraic set of an homogeneous ideal. The book I'm using states that an homogeneous ideal is an ideal which contains all the homogeneous parts of the polynomials that it contains, and is equivalent to saying that it's generated by homogeneous polynomials. This looks fine and relatively clear.

Now, when we define the algebraic set, that later we'll call variety, we say that if $I$ is an homogeneous ideal, $V(I) = \{P \in P^n_{K}\ | f(P) = 0$ for all homogeneous $f \in I \}$.

Now, does this mean that it's defined as in the affine case? Because if all the homogeneous components lie in $I$, then for any $f = f_{0} + \ldots + f_{d}$ where $f_{i} =$ the homogeneous component of $f$ of degree $i$, $f_{i} (P) = 0$ and then $f(P) = f_{0}(P) + \ldots + f_{d}(P) = 0$. I think this flows relatively well but then it makes no sense that in the definition given by the book, the condition is only applied to homogeneous polynomials. Am I right or am I missing something huge? I'm pretty insicure about it because I don't know anyone who I can talk with about these things, and clear my doubts, so thank you in advance!

Comment: include information on the book you are reading and define thing properly - then it is much easier for users of this forum to respond.

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is a point in a projective space, then the relation $f(P) = 0$ is only well defined for homogeneous polynomials.

A point is a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_K$ is defined as a line through origin in $K^{n + 1}$, or the equivalence class of points in $K^{n + 1}\setminus\{0\}$ under equivalence relation defined by $v \sim \lambda v$ for all $\lambda \in K$.

In other words, a point $P$ in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_K$ is given by $n + 1$ scalars (called homogeneous coordinates), which is usually denotes by $P = (P_0:P_1:\dots:P_n)$, but these coordinates are not defined uniquely, only up to scaling: $(P_0:P_1:\dots:P_n) = (\lambda P_0: \lambda P_1:\dots:\lambda P_n)$.

Now, if a polynomial $f$ is homogeneous of degree $d$, then $f(\lambda P_0, \dots, \lambda P_n) = \lambda^d f(P_0, \dots, P_n)$, so the relation $f(P) = 0$ is invariant under scaling and this gives us a well-defined notion of $f(P) = 0$ for $P \in \mathbb{P}^n_K$. But if $f$ is not homogeneous, then it is possible that $f(P_0, \dots, P_n) = 0$ and $f(\lambda P_0, \dots, \lambda P_n) \neq 0$, so vanishing of a non-homogeneous polynomial on a point in a projective space is not well defined.

Comment: That is what confuses me, because I agree with all this, and I have no problem understanding the need of homogeneous polynomials. The thing is, am I wrong for saying that if we define $V(I)$ as the points where all homogeneous polynomials in I vanish, then by splitting any polynomial in its homogeneous components (based on degree), these lie in $I$ since it is homogeneous, and by definition they all vanish in points of V(I), so all polynomials vanish? I understand that for non homogeneous ideals it is not well defined, but why wouldn’t it be?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the ideal is homogeneous, then all polynomials in this ideal will vanish on all affine points corresponding to the projective points in $V$.